# Level 2 nest bar chart

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I have a level 2 nest where an array of states have been averaged by male and female in an array of two values ie :

```
let nest2 = d3.nest()
.key(function(d){return d.state;})
.key(function(d){return d.gender;})
.rollup(function(v)  { return d3.mean(v, function(d) { return d.proficient; }); })
.entries(data);
```

I want to display the percentage of the values in the level two nest when it's selected in my dropdown.  For a single variable key nest I simply use:

```
.text(function(d){return d.value})
```

Any ideas on how to access the values in the level 2 nest?  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

To access the second level data a change in the key is added to the state you are interested in viewing ie:

```
.key(function(d){return d.state == 'desiredstate' ;})
```